# Converting componentDidMount and componentWillUnmount

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am currently attempting to convert the [React + Material UI + Firebase](https://github.com/Phoqe/react-material-ui-firebase) template over using React hooks. Right now I am trying to convert the lifecycle methods in [App.js](https://github.com/Phoqe/react-material-ui-firebase/blob/master/src/components/App/App.js) over to useEffect so far, this is what I have

```
useEffect(() => {
setMounted(true)

const removeAuthStateChangedObserver = auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
  //* if there is no user...
  if (!user) {
    if (removeReferenceListener) {
      removeReferenceListener()
    }

    if (mounted) {
      setUser(null)
      setUserData(null)
      setSignedIn(false)
      setReady(true)
    }

    return

  }

  const uid = user.uid

  //* if there is no uid...
  if (!uid) {
    if (removeReferenceListener) {
      removeReferenceListener()
    }

    if (mounted) {
      setUser(null)
      setUserData(null)
      setSignedIn(false)
      setReady(true)
    }

    return

  }

  const reference = firestore.collection('users').doc(uid)

  //* if there is no reference...
  if (!reference) {
    if (this.removeReferenceListener) {
      this.removeReferenceListener();
    }

    if (mounted) {
      setUser(null)
      setUserData(null)
      setSignedIn(false)
      setReady(true)
    }

    return

  }

  const removeReferenceListener = reference.onSnapshot((snapshot) => { //!ADDED CONST HERE INSTEAD OF THIS
    if (!snapshot.exists) {
      if (removeReferenceListener) {
        removeReferenceListener();
      }

      if (mounted) {
        setUser(null)
        setUserData(null)
        setSignedIn(false)
        setReady(true)
      }

      return

    }

    const data = snapshot.data();

    if (!data) {
      if (removeReferenceListener) {
        removeReferenceListener();
      }

      if (mounted) {
        setUser(null)
        setUserData(null)
        setSignedIn(false)
        setReady(true)
      }

      return

    }

    if (mounted) {
      setUser(user)
      setUserData(data)
      setSignedIn(true)
      setReady(true)
    }

  })
})

//!FOR THE componentWillUnmount
return () => {
  if (removeAuthStateChangedObserver) {
    removeAuthStateChangedObserver();
  }

  if (removeReferenceListener) {
    removeReferenceListener();
  }

  setMounted(false);
}}, [mounted])
```

Here, have defined my variables, user, userData, signedIn, ready using useState hook notation. I am getting a few errors with ESlint telling me to put declaration before the method checks or how 'removeReferenceListener' is not defined in the final return statement for componentWillUnmount.

If someone could lend me a hand, this would be super important since this is one of the most important methods in the application for signing users up. Here is the [link](https://github.com/MedChain-CS506/client) to what I already have also if it is more helpful. Thanks

Comment: What is removeReferenceListener? I can't find documentation on it. Also the code you posted in your question does not seem to be the same as the [code on github](https://github.com/MedChain-CS506/client/blob/master/src/App.js)

Comment: You don't need to check mounted every time since the App component [will never unmount](https://github.com/MedChain-CS506/client/blob/master/src/index.js)

Answer (score 0):

I have formatted your code with some comments

```
useEffect(() => {
  const removeAuthStateChangedObserver = auth.onAuthStateChanged(
    user => {
      //* if there is no user...
      if (!user) {
        //why would you try to do this? This only runs on the first mount
        //  and you didn't create removeReferenceListener yet
        // if (removeReferenceListener) {
        //   removeReferenceListener();
        // }
        //just set the state, App will never unmount
        setUser(null);
        setUserData(null);
        setSignedIn(false);
        setReady(true);

        return;
      }

      const uid = user.uid;

      //* if there is no uid...
      if (!uid) {
        //again trying to call removeReferenceListener when it wasn't created
        //  yet
        // if (removeReferenceListener) {
        //   removeReferenceListener();
        // }

        setUser(null);
        setUserData(null);
        setSignedIn(false);
        setReady(true);

        return;
      }

      const reference = firestore
        .collection('users')
        .doc(uid);

      //* if there is no reference...
      if (!reference) {
        //you still didn't create removeReferenceListener, why keep trying to
        //  call it?
        // if (removeReferenceListener) {
        //   removeReferenceListener();
        // }

        setUser(null);
        setUserData(null);
        setSignedIn(false);
        setReady(true);

        return;
      }
      //now you finally create removeReferenceListener and you want to call this
      //  if App unmounts, but App never unmounts?
      const removeReferenceListener = reference.onSnapshot(
        snapshot => {
          //!ADDED CONST HERE INSTEAD OF THIS
          if (!snapshot.exists) {
            if (removeReferenceListener) {
              removeReferenceListener();
            }

            setUser(null);
            setUserData(null);
            setSignedIn(false);
            setReady(true);

            return;
          }

          const data = snapshot.data();

          if (!data) {
            if (removeReferenceListener) {
              removeReferenceListener();
            }

            setUser(null);
            setUserData(null);
            setSignedIn(false);
            setReady(true);

            return;
          }

          setUser(user);
          setUserData(data);
          setSignedIn(true);
          setReady(true);
        }
      );
    }
  );

  //!FOR THE componentWillUnmount
  //  WHY? show me how the component will unmount
  return () => {
    if (removeAuthStateChangedObserver) {
      removeAuthStateChangedObserver();
    }
    //removeReferenceListener is not even in scope here, you could put it in scope
    //  but why would you? Returning a cleanup function is pointless because
    //  App will only mount once and never unmount
    // if (removeReferenceListener) {
    //   removeReferenceListener();
    // }
  };
}, []);
```